# perf_event_open - unable to monitor HW_CACHE write and prefetch events

Tags: android, c, linux, profiling, perf

I am attempting to monitor `PERF_TYPE_HW_CACHE` events. I have found that I am able to measure read accesses and misses for each cache, but if I try to measure write or prefetch accesses/misses the config does not register. Using the following code:

```
struct read_format {
  uint64_t nr;          /* The number of events */
  struct {
    uint64_t value;     /* The value of the event */
    uint64_t id;        /* if PERF_FORMAT_ID */
  } values[nr];
};

int main() {
  struct perf_event_attr attr1;
  attr1.type = PERF_TYPE_HW_CACHE;
  attr1.config = ((PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_L1D) | (PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_OP_READ << 8) | (PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_RESULT_ACCESS << 16));
  attr1.read_format = PERF_FORMAT_GROUP | PERF_FORMAT_ID;
  int main_fd = syscall(__NR_perf_event_open, &attr1, 0, -1, -1, 0);
  uint64_t id1;
  ioctl(main_fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ID, &id1);
  ioctl(main_fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET, 0);
  ioctl(main_fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, 0);

  struct perf_event_attr attr2;
  attr2.type = PERF_TYPE_HW_CACHE;
  attr2.config = ((PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_L1D) | (PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_OP_READ << 8) | (PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_RESULT_MISS<< 16));
  attr2.read_format = PERF_FORMAT_GROUP | PERF_FORMAT_ID;
  int fd2 = syscall(__NR_perf_event_open, &attr2, 0, -1, main_fd, 0);
  uint64_t id2;
  ioctl(fd2, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ID, &id2);
  ioctl(fd2, PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET, 0);
  ioctl(fd2, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, 0);

  // read_values and log "START"

  // action

  // read_values and log "END"

  return 0;
}

read_values() {
  char buffer[4096];
  int read_bytes = read(main_fd, &buffer, sizeof(buffer));
  if (read_bytes == -1) { return 1; }

  struct read_format* rf = (struct read_format*) buffer;
  int values[rf->nr];
  for (int i=0; i<rf->nr; i++) {
    values[i] = rf->values[i].value;
  }
}
```

In the above code, I am able to monitor the level 1 data cache read accesses and misses just fine. The problem is when I attempt to change the `perf_hw_cache_op_id` from `PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_OP_READ` to either `PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_OP_WRITE` or `PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_OP_PREFETCH` I find that the events do not get registered into the fd.

```
// This config works fine
attr1.config = ((PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_L1D) | (PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_OP_READ << 8) | (PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_RESULT_ACCESS << 16));

// These configs do not work
attr1.config = ((PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_L1D) | (PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_OP_WRITE << 8) | (PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_RESULT_ACCESS << 16));
attr1.config = ((PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_L1D) | (PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_OP_PREFETCH<< 8) | (PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_RESULT_ACCESS << 16));
```

If I change the `perf_hw_cache_id` from `PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_L1D` to any of the other options (i.e. `PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_L1I` or `PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_LL`), I find the same behavior (read accesses/misses work as expected, write/prefetch does not work).